# The Riddle of Life

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, wordplay

I'm neither at the beginning of it, nor at the end of it, however without me life would just be incomplete.

Hint:

> This is a logical riddle.

Comment: I didn't read the word Spoiler and thought it was a hint. I didn't think you'd actually put the answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> the word "if" ? It appears in the middle of the word life, neither at the beginning nor the end, and the word itself would not be complete without it.

Comment: Yes :D - I have to wait 9 more minutes to select it as answer xD

Comment: Please add an explanation of the answer (even if it seems obvious).

Comment: @f'' added an explanation as requested.

Comment: @ULI-R0 f'' was asking C. Woods to flesh out his answer (which he did). You don't need to put the explanation in your question itself.

Answer (score 4):

I see the question was already answered correctly by C.Woods, but I was going to say

> The middle, as in the middle of life itself, rather than the actual word.  It's not the beginning or the end however without the middle, life would just be incomplete. It ended up being the middle of the actual word "life"

Comment: I would say that it is acceptable as it counts toward the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was...

> the 'F' letter: not at beginning or end, but without it LIFE is incomplete (it is a LIE). On second thought, there is also the F word: not at the beginning (too young) or end (too old!), but without it life is incomplete (get a LIFE!). Actually, without it there would be no life at all.

Now don't ask me why people in France call it "la petite mort" (the small death)...